# Can I check instance presence at runtime?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I have a data family of finite vectors:

```
data family Vec (n :: Nat) e
data instance Vec 2 Float = Vec2f !Float !Float
data instance Vec 3 Float = Vec3f !Float !Float !Float
-- and so on
```

I also have a family of getter functions:

```
class Get (i :: Nat) (n :: Nat) e where
    get :: Vec n e -> e

instance Get 0 2 Float where
    get (Vec2f x _) = x

instance Get 1 2 Float where
    get (Vec2f _ x) = x

instance Get 0 3 Float where
    get (Vec3f x _ _) = x

instance Get 1 3 Float where
    get (Vec3f _ x _) = x

instance Get 2 3 Float where
    get (Vec3f _ _ x) = x
-- and so on
```

This way, access to elements of a vector is checked at compile time, so this compiles:

```
get @0 (Vec2f 0 1)
```

and this doesn't:

```
get @4 (Vec2f 0 1)
```

Now, I wonder if I can write runtime range check using those functions.
I tried this:

```
get' :: forall n e. (KnownNat n) => Integer -> Vec n e -> Maybe e
get' i v =
    if i >= 0 && i < natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
        then (flip fmap) (someNatVal i) $ \(SomeNat (Proxy :: Proxy i)) ->
            get @i v -- Could not deduce (Get i n e)
        else Nothing
```

I think I have to check presence of `Get i n e` instance at runtime, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any easy way.

Haskell is designed so that all the type-level stuff can be erased at runtime. The only way I know out of this is to exploit `KnownNat` and `Typeable` and manually check against each instance. E.g. something like:

```
get' :: forall n e. (Typeable e, KnownNat n) => Integer -> Vec n e -> Maybe e
get' 0 v =
    case sameNat (Proxy @n) (Proxy @2) of
      Just Refl -> case eqT :: Maybe (e :~: Float) of
                     Just Refl -> Just $ get @0 v
                     Nothing -> Nothing  -- TODO check for e/=Float
      Nothing -> case sameNat (Proxy @n) (Proxy @3) of
         Just Refl -> case eqT :: Maybe (e :~: Float) of
            Just Refl -> Just $ get @0 v
            Nothing -> Nothing  -- TODO check for e/=Float
         Nothing -> Nothing -- TODO check for n/=2,3
get' i v = Nothing -- TODO check for i>0
```

(This could probably use some factoring...)

Probably a better approach would be to define a list (or whatever) of reified dictionaries, and loop over it. One would need to keep such list in sync with the actual instances, though.

Perhaps in the future Haskell will get the typeclass search machinery at runtime as well. So far, this was not done, I guess, because moving to runtime type-level checks is quite unidiomatic in Haskell. However, after we got `DataKinds` and `KnownNat` and similar stuff, perhaps reification/"reflection" of static information at runtime has become more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

One issue right now is that `Get`'s instances are all kind of ad-hoc, so it's hard to provide a clean solution.  If you're willing to refactor `Get` a bit, it's a lot simpler:

```
class Get (n :: Nat) e where
    get :: (KnownNat i, i <= (n-1)) => Proxy i -> Vec n e -> e

instance Get 2 Float where
    get :: (KnownNat i, i <= 1) => Proxy i -> Vec 2 Float -> Float
    get p (Vec2f x y) = case natVal p of
      0 -> x
      1 -> y
      _ -> error ":("
```

Then you can do

```
get' :: forall n e. (Get n e, KnownNat (n - 1)) => Integer -> Vec n e -> Maybe e
get' i v = do
    -- bring KnownNat i into context
    SomeNat (iProx@Proxy) <- someNatVal i           -- will be Nothing if i < 0
    -- bring i <= (n - 1) into context
    Refl          <- iProx `isLE` (Proxy @(n - 1))  -- will be Nothing if i >= n
    return (get iProx v)
```

Using [GHC.TypeLits.Compare](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/typelits-witnesses-0.2.3.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits-Compare.html) from the typelits-witnesses library to bring the inequality constraint into the context for GHC to use.

Comment: What is `p` in the last line `return (get p v)`? Did you mean `iProx`?

Comment: @AlexeyVagarenko yes, sorry!  changed the name of the variable during an edit, and forgot to swap that instance.